# Android Studio taskbar icon on first start wrong (Linux)

Tags: linux, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a strange behaviour after updating to Android Studio 3.6.
When I start the IDE for the first time after boot, the taskbar icon looks different than usual. If I open a second project, it is the right one. I use Linux Mint.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I found a ticket, it is IntelliJ related: 
[Link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222948?_ga=2.68060241.1908649337.1584618311-2083496080.1575374466&_gac=1.121116922.1583747830.Cj0KCQjw0pfzBRCOARIsANi0g0uO0rn6mzXijOvP5pBENlZjUoQ8BTs3iw8dxfnhDljvgK1VQSDRa7saApGvEALw_wcB)

**EDIT 2**
Still not fixed in Android Studio 4.0

**EDIT 3**
Seems to be a problem in cinnamon, not IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works since Linux Mint 20. Was cinnamon related, had nothing to do with InteliJ.